# boost asio передача числа

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Здравствуйте! 
Пишу клиентское приложение с использованием boost asio. Есть необходимость передавать на сервер число в виде int (не char). В примерах встречал только char. Есть мысли?

Comment: int это просто `char[4]` (обычно). Дальше справитесь?

Comment: да, понял, спасибо)